# jQuery 3.3.1 update gives Chrome/Safari error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Chrome uses 4 different User Agents apparently and I'm getting the following error after jQuery 3.3.1 upgrade, reporting from Safari:

```
'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'e.getAttribute("type")')
```

There's little to no help in the stack trace other than it originates from the jquery min file.

Has anyone else seen this issue being reported on Safari, or even Chrome since it's telling my server that it's User Agent is "safari" for whatever reason? Something with jQuery 3.3.1 and iOS 11/Chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery 3 only supports last 2 versions of Safari, see https://jquery.com/browser-support/. Safari on Windows is 6 versions behind the latest version (currently 11) so it's no longer supported.

Referrer : https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4008

Comment: Perfect! Thank you